# Difference between queries in Studio3t and their equivalent with Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a database with a collection `users` `id,...,subscribedFlux`. Each `id` can have several `subscribedFlux` and I want to know how much `Flux` have been subscribed. The query worked well with Studio3t giving the expected results :

When I do it using Pymongo, I don't get anything:

```
:~$ python testMongoDB.py 
/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py:555: UserWarning: Unknown option 3t.databases
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py:555: UserWarning: Unknown option 3t.uriVersion
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py:555: UserWarning: Unknown option 3t.connectionMode
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
/home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/common.py:555: UserWarning: Unknown option 3t.connection.name
  warnings.warn(str(exc))
```

Here is the script I am using (I have hidden the database address):

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pymongo
import datetime
import pprint

from pymongo import MongoClient


client = MongoClient('mongodb://swiper_read:swiper_read@3...ESCONDIDO')

db = MongoClient().aggregation_example
cursor = db.users.aggregate(
    [
        #{"$match": {"subscribedFlux": { "$exists": "true" }}},
        {"$group": {"_id": "$subscribedFlux", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
    ]
)

for document in cursor:
    print (document)
```

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your code please? How did you define your `db` variable?

Comment: @errata I have provided what was missing and noticed I had badly written the collection name which is `users` and not restaurant. Yet it doesn't affect the provided results.

Comment: @errata I think, I have hidden some parts because I think it is sensible. At least it is the one I used when connecting to it in studio3t within "import URI" option in "Connect". It is a read only one that is online. Maybe there is an alternative to that ? I succeeded with the example database and queries provided by [docs.mongodb.com](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/python/aggregation/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't pass 'unknown' options to your MongoDB URI like you are doing at the moment with `3t.databases`, `3t.uriVersion` etc... Instead, try this:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://user:pass@ip:port/')  # pass just these options

db = client.DATABASE_NAME  # or client['DATABASE_NAME']
cursor = db.TABLE_NAME.aggregate(
    [
        #{"$match": {"subscribedFlux": { "$exists": "true" }}},
        {"$group": {"_id": "$subscribedFlux", "count": {"$sum": 1}}}
    ]
)
```

Comment: It still shows different results from the one I have in studio3t ... `aggregation_example` was a name I created from nowhere when reading other sources on the web.

Comment: @AntoineCoppin Hm, running your example with my local MongoDB resulted in some data. Can you double/triple check that you are connecting to same database in Studio 3T and in your Python code?

Comment: Hmmm... just tried with both read-only and plain database. It works on studio3t, I have no idea about python as far as the only answer I get from the example above is the few warning lines that are above. Maybe I could share you the read-only address on a private channel to allow you test it ?

Comment: Well that is doable :) If you increase your StackOverflow reputation a bit, we could start a chat and discuss it there...?

Comment: Oh... I wish I had !

Comment: Can you try to join this chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145379/temp

Comment: I can't I don't have enough reputation but a friend of mine just arrived home may he join ? His pseudo is @Marine1